# Everyday the DBs are in Recovery pending state

Tags: database-administration, sql-server-2016

I have an Azure Virtual Machine hosting a SQL Server 2016 named instance. On this instance I have several DBs. Now, everyday we shutdown the virtual machine at 11.59PM and restart it at 8.00AM. The problem is that everyday I find **some** of the DBs in the "RECOVERY PENDING" status. This is very annoying because I must then execute a SQL script to pute the DBs in the normal status.

Do you have any cue why this is happening everyday on some (but always the same) of the DBs?

Thank you

Comment: How do you shut down the server? Just via Azure or do you have a scheduled task? Do you stop the service before you turn it off?

Comment: @jstuart-tech I use the "shutdown" feature of the Azure Virtual Machine in the Azure portal. Moreover, I already shut down in this way other virtual machines that host other SQL Server instances and none of them have this problem when turned on

Comment: And yet, on the same virtual machine that has this problem I have other named instances and those are started correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the SQL server logs I finally fixed the problem. Simply, the "RECOVERY PENDING" DBs need the FILESTREAM feature enabled, but the SQL Server instance did not have that feature enabled. I only had to [enable the FILESTREAM feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/enable-and-configure-filestream?view=sql-server-ver15#to-enable-and-change-filestream-settings) on the SQL Server instance